# Xcode 8.2.1 Failed to codesign archive

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload an archive for test flight to itunesconnect. However, when I go to validate the archive I get an error message saying that code signing failed and that a .ipa file is missing. I have scoured the internet for quite some time and can't find a viable solution to fixing this problem.

Xcode: Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)
Deployment Target: iOS 8.0+

IDEDistribution.standard.log:

`2017-03-15 20:25:03 +0000 [MT] Validation failed for archive ******* with issues: IDEDistributionIssue: severity(error), error(Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-21013 \"The archive is invalid. /var/folders/yc/y1chf6z95zj63mnsw7m6qwm80000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.6rX/Packages/*******.ipa does not exist.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The archive is invalid. /var/folders/yc/y1chf6z95zj63mnsw7m6qwm80000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.6rX/Packages/*******.ipa does not exist., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.})`

IDEDistribution.critical.log

`2017-03-15 20:19:52 +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=1 "Codesign failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Codesign failed}`

[image: Archive Error]

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. We are using Carthage libraries in the project, and I guess the code signing of the libraries we were using didn't like our project for some reason. I manually placed the source code for the libraries into the project and it ran fine.